# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not displayed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<DIV class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-column16" style="CURSOR: pointer" unselectable="on">IMG title="Copy password" style="FLOAT: left; MARGIN: 0px 3px 0px 0px; DISPLAY: block" src="images/icons/password_copy.gif" border=0></DIV>
```

Trying to get the element by

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='images/icons/password_copy.gif']") 
Or elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='Copy password']")
```

`Elem.click()` - not working
But not able to click the element. Getting error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not displayed.
```

Can someone please get me the workaround

Comment: the HTML you provided is in valid!

Comment: The issue is not in the htlml, I'm looking forward for a solution to the above exception

Comment: There's not much point in providing HTML if it's not even valid. Fix the HTML. Have you tried adding a `WebDriverWait` until clickable? That error just means that the element you are trying to click isn't visible which means you can't interact with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around this is using ActionChains provided in Selenium

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elem = driver.find_element #complete xpath
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with #complete where you want to move element
action.click()
action.perform()
```

You can read more about XPath ActionChains documentation.

Comment: Hi Xion, thank you for your time. I'm fairly new to the selenium, can you please care to explain how actionchain is going to prevent the above mentioned exception from throwing

Comment: @SunnyDhaiya ActionChain is like mouse movement. I also had problem with elements since sometimes it would appear hidden lets say if you have pop up and such. Xpath is good to use but sometimes doesn't work well with pop up windows or site that has hidden layers that can conflict when using selenium.

So ActionChain will act like as if you are using a mouse.
On the Side Note(if you don't know about it yet): On the Console (Inspect Element) you can click on certain spot, it will highlight in the console and you can just copy xpath, which can help you a lot too. Also I suggest use import time

Comment: It didn't work Xion, trying to get the x and y coordinate as well but not getting it only for this element......                           Location = elem.location   print (location)

Comment: actions.move_to_element_with_offset(element, 5, 5), you will have to determine the element based on the size of the browser or field of the element you are trying to get. Think about it and try to see if you can grab the element. I have only learn selenium for 3 weeks and I had tons of trial and errors. To be able to get good at selenium even now I am still learning, look around google. Once you understand it you will be using ActionChains, Xpath, CSS and others very quickly

Comment: Thanks Xion for your valuable time and great advice. But the code is just not working. Now I have shifted to chrome from IE. And it is working as intended. Have already learned quite a few things. Still thanks for all your help.